# Static string initialization order issue

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dynamic-linking, static-initialization

I have `extern const` string declaration in a header file, and it's definition in source file:

```
// a.h
extern const std::string base;

// a.cpp
const std::string base = "base";
```

Then I have another `extern const` string in another header file, and the definition of this string uses the definition of the first string:

```
// b.h
extern const std::string usage;

// b.cpp
const std::string usage = base + " str";
```

At application launch I get this error:

> A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

I attached the debugger to the application, got the following exception thrown:

> Exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr.

This was thrown at `base` in `b.cpp`. So I gathered this is issue of static initialization order. But in my make-file I'm listing `a.obj` BEFORE `b.obj` so I don't get why this happens.

Please note that I get this error only on *Windows*. Linux is fine.

One remedy is to define `base` in header file:

```
// a.h
const std::string base = "base";

// a.cpp
```

Is this the only solution? Or there's a better way?

Comment: consider putting `base` in a function returning a local static variable see: https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/languages/c-plus-plus/magic-statics/

Comment: Sadly, this is a recurrent issue on Windows (especially using MSVC). Please do not use non-POD extern global variables as it cause a lot of issues (and not only on Windows). Moreover, note that if this is a compile-time constant, using a C++20 `constexpr` string or a C++17 `constexpr std::string_view` may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can control order of initialization with [`#pragma init_seg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/init-seg?view=vs-2019)

pointers to *c++* initializes by default placed in section `.CRT$XCU` (between `__xc_a` from `.CRT$XCA` and `__xc_z` from `.CRT$XCZ`  )

so solution can be next

```
// a.cpp
#pragma warning(disable : 4075)
#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCU1")

const std::string base = "base";
```

and

```
// b.cpp
#pragma warning(disable : 4075)
#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCU2")

const std::string usage = base + " str";
```

so put `base` to `".CRT$XCU1"` and `usage` to `".CRT$XCU2"` this guarantee that `base` will be init before `usage`

Comment: Thanks for info, I didn't know about this, I used this and it worked like charm! Anyways, is it common to use it for such situations? Because I never heard of this solution. Also, if I need `base` in more than one source files, should I use the same `".CRT$XCU2"` in every file? Or I need to use `".CRT$XCU3"`, etc.?

Comment: @bb8 - you need understand how this work internally. how function [`initterm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/initterm-initterm-e?view=vs-2019) work. when you declare global variable, which need initialization - compiler allocate internal variable (`_PVFV` type - pointer to function which call constructor to your object. *crt* declare `__xc_a` and `__xc_z` variable and place it in special section - and call `initterm(&__xc_z, &__xc_z)`. look in *crt\src\vcruntime\initializers.cpp* and other files in *vcruntime* also look in map file

Comment: @bb8 - *if I need base in more than one source files, should I use the same `".CRT$XCU2"` in every file?* - yes, can and use `".CRT$XCU3"` - no different - main that section name in A-Z order must be after `".CRT$XCU1"` - so 2 or 3 - no different, both after 1 of course better not create additional section if not need. so use `".CRT$XCU2"`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why title has mentioned static strings initialization, and probably this behavior depends on compiler been used, but with vs2017 you should include a.h header in b.cpp file. It worked for me. Thanks.